# UIPanGestureRecognizer in a UITableViewCell not recognizing left Pan

Tags: ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

Right now I am developing an iPad app that uses a subclass of UITableviewCell that uses UIPanGestureRecognizer to slide left and right, However it only slides right and dosent slide left... This is the code I am usuing:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString           *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) 
    {
    // Initialization code
                  UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self        action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    pan.delegate = self;

    [self addGestureRecognizer:pan];

}
return self;
}
```

This is my handlePan: method,

```
 CGPoint translation = [gesture locationInView:self];
    self.center = CGPointMake(self.center.x + translation.x,
                              self.center.y);
    if (self.center.x > 700) {
        NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.tag],@"number",nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"right" object:nil userInfo:dic];
        dic = nil;
    }
    if (self.center.x < 0){
        NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.tag],@"number",nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"left" object:nil userInfo:dic];
        dic = nil;
        NSLog(@"Left Called");


    }
    [gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self];
```

No matter what I try, i cant seem to get the console to say "Left Called" , i.e. The cell slides left. I am really struggling with this issue and would appreciate any help at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to react to the changed state of the pan, and the center calculation can be much simpler...

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {

    if ((gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) ||
        (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)) {

        CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake([gesture locationInView:self.superview].x, self.center.y);
        self.center = newCenter;

        // To determine the direction of the pan, check the sign of translation in view.
        // This supplies the cumulative translation...
        if ([gesture translationInView:self.superview].x > 0) {
            NSLog(@">>>");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"<<<");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use this code, how can I detect the direction of the slide, (i.e. left and right detection). Thank you

Comment: Thank You. This greatly Simplifies the process and makes the code easier AND makes it faster! It also solved my problem... I wish I could upvote this more times!

Answer (score 1):

I think the way that you are determining left/right might be flawed.

```
CGPoint translation = [gesture locationInView:self];
self.center = CGPointMake(self.center.x + translation.x,
                              self.center.y);
```

self.center.x will always be positive since "translation" is the location in the view which is positive.
What you probably want to keep track of the original touch position and then compare that with the location when swiping/moving. Try something like this:

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panRecognizer {

    if (panRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        // create a local property for the original point and assign the position on first touch
        self.originalPanTouchPoint = [panRecognizer locationInView:self.view];
        // create a local property for cell's center prior to pan
        self.initialCellCenter = self.center;
    } else {
        CGPoint currentTouchPoint = [panRecognizer locationInView:self.view];
        CGFloat xTranslation = self.originalPanTouchPoint.x - currentTouchPoint.x;

        self.center = CGPointMake(self.initialCellCenter.x + xTranslation, self.initialCellCenter.y);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried you code, and the cell itself dosent move now, I was using self.center = CGPointMake(self.center.x + translation.x,
                              self.center.y); to actually move the cell...

Comment: I edited to code to move the cell. The point is that when using the pan gesture recognizer you need to compare the touch point when the gesture began with the touch point when dragged to find the translation. [panRecognizer locationInView:self.view] only gives you the current touch point and not the translation.